# php regular expression error

Tags: php, regex

I am using following regular expression to match the url paths

```
<?php
  $path1 = 'user/3/categories';
  $path1 = 'user/3';
  $re = /^user\/[0-9]+\/?$/;
  $match =  preg_match($re, $path1);
  echo $match;
  $match =  preg_match($re, $path2);
  echo $match;
```

My expected answer should print 0 and 1, However I am getting error in regular expresion in line 3. What is error I am making ?

Comment: Unlike javascript in php regex patterns are strings. use `$re = '/^user\/[0-9]+\/?$/';`. [Here's](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1ybUEg) solution and how it was fixed. so you can realize mistakes in a case you're new to php.

Comment: You can also use another delimiter to simplify the pattern: `'~^user/[0-9]+/?$~';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the quotes

`$re = '/^user\/[0-9]+\/?$/';`

Comment: wrapping inside quotes fixed problem. Learned that in php regex are not a data type in itself. Thanks everyone